# How can I change the port of a React App running inside docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I was dockerising an app of mine but I wanted to access it on port 80 on my machine, every time a change the port in `docker-composer.yml` it returnes the error:

```
ERROR: for site  Cannot create container for service site: mount denied:
the source path "dcfffb89fd376c0d955b0903e3aae045df32a073a6743c7e44b3214325700576:D:\\projetos\\portfolio\\site\\node_modules:rw"
too many colons
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

> Im running on windows

#### docker-composer.yml

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  site:
    container_name: site
    build: ./site
    volumes:
      - 'D:\projetos\portfolio\site'
      - 'D:\projetos\portfolio\site\node_modules'
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
      - COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=true
    command: npm start
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16.13.1-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 
COPY package*.json ./
 
RUN npm install
 
COPY . .
 
EXPOSE 3000
 
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Answer (score -1):

I was using the wrong path pattern, on windows you have to use `/c/path/to/volume` since the ":" is used inside docker stuff(don't know what), also removed the command `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=true` and worked just fine.